# jScrollPane - scrollbar doesn't show

Tags: jquery, css, jscrollpane

I'm trying to use jScrollPane on a CSS class but it's not working. You can view the setup [here](http://www.noahd.net/demo-upwall/approach/).

I've included the jScrollPane.css and jScrollPane.js in header, and used this function to apply jScroll to the `.content-wrap` class.

```
jQuery(function()
{
jQuery('.content-wrap').jScrollPane({showArrows:true});
});
```

The script is working but only partially. I can see that the `.content-wrap` class is being modified by the `jScrollPane` class but the scrollbar doesn't show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation, I figured out that there is something wrong with your jscrollpane javascript file. Have you been tampering with it? I got suspiscious because it was adding 'classname' attribute.

As you can see in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BVJpA/1/) your scrollbar appears.

All I did was change the source of the scrollpane.js and css to the official one and the scrollbars started to work.

Comment: You're right, for some reason I was using other jScrollPane files, that I though were the last versions from the official site. Apparently they were not, and now it is working. Thanks, I really appreciate the help!